# How to change the format of the subcriber email

Tags: email

How do I change the format of the subscriber email so that they need to click a link back to our page to see the full post, instead of emailing the whole post?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Jetpack blog subscriptions ? if yes, you will need to insert read more tag ( `<!--more-->` ) where you want the post excerpt to stop, and Jetpack will do the same in the email sent to subscribers, giving them a read more link.